# How to get rid of installing OpenCV in Ubuntu which is needed by SikuliX API

Tags: java, opencv, ubuntu, packing, sikuli-x

I have bundled the SikuliX 2.0.3 Jar in my java application. At run-time, this jar file needs access to the OpenCV library from java.library.path. So, I need to install OpenCV on the library path (/usr/lib). 
I wanted to know if is there any way I can bundle OpenCV in my application and SikuliX Jar can access this library within the same application. I don't want the client to take care of installing this OpenCV library, which could be a cumbersome task for them.
If the above case is not possible then any other suggestions are very much appreciated.

FYI - Since SikuliX is an open-source library, I have access to its code.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who has same problem, I got solution as - 
I had build the OpenCV from source with static linking and then use those libraries within my application.
One can refer [here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-opencv-on-ubuntu-18-04/) for building opencv from source.
Also make sure to set BUILD_SHARED_LIBS flag to false/off:

```
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF ..
```